# How to find td value with same tr's ID in jQuery

Tags: jquery, foreach, html-table

I have an HTML table with rows made with a foreach loop like this:

```html
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr id="tr1" class="text-center" onClick="HighLightTR(this, '7ED1E6', 'cc3333');" >
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InternalMedicineCode)
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tbl_InternalMedicine.InternalMedicineName)
            </td>
            <td id="td2">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dose)
            </td>
            <td class="hidden" id="td1">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.IdTherapyRegistration)
            </td>
```

When I click on a row, I want to alert the value of the cell that is hidden and its id is `td1`. I don't know how to do it with jQuery. My jQuery function code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#myTable").on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

            var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text();
            alert(col1);
        });
    });
```

but I can't get this id.

Comment: You should use a `class` instead of an `id`. 
Put a class on your `tr` and define an event listener on this class.

Comment: Can you show me an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are able to use a `class` instead of an `id`, on your `tr`, here is the solution.

First, replace this:

```
<tr id="tr1" class="text-center" onClick="HighLightTR(this, '7ED1E6', 'cc3333');" >
```

By this:

```
<tr class="text-center tr-clickable" onClick="HighLightTR(this, '7ED1E6', 'cc3333');" >
```

And then, update your jQuery function like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".tr-clickable").on("click", function() {
    var currentRow = $(this);
    var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text();
    
    alert(col1);
  })
  
});
```

Comment: No problem! Have a nice coding!

Answer (score 0):

You should have defined the event on td and not tr.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#myTable tr").(function (){
            var currentRow = $(this);

            var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text();
            alert(col1);
        });
    });
```

Comment: this td is hidden,so i can't click on this!
i try your code,but i don't get any answer :(

Comment: You would define the event on the entire tds. So it wouldn't matter which td is clicked.

Comment: how can define event on tds??

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#myTable").find('td').each({
           $(this).click(function () { // here has error "The use of a keyword for an identifier is invalid".
            var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

            var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text();
            alert(col1);
            });
        });
    });

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work!
However thanks for your help ;)

Comment: I have no idea what to say.